# MvvmCross crashes on app start with "Method 'Array.Empty' not found" exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have recently updated my Xamarin.Android app MvvmCross package from `4.1.4` to `4.1.5` and now unable to launch my app. Couldn't even debug the issue as long as my code doesn't get any control before the crash.

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found.
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00055] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1 eventArgs) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0
  at at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise[T] (System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler, System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.T value) [0x00000] in C:\vcs\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Core\MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.cs:21
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxSplashScreenActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00017] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3236/ee215fc9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2857
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:97318edf-ae39-4dd0-a17c-810218756b0b (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

- clean / rebuild doesn't help
- rollback to `4.1.4` restores the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a current issue with MVVMCross and Mono. More information about it here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1330